# How large and different is the Harry Potter world?

Tags: harry-potter

I live in Russia and I wonder if the Harry Potter books take place in London and the language there is English, and Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them is set in America, which is an English-speaking country too, does that mean that the core of the Harry Potter world is built around English speaking countries only? Well, the Triwizard Tournament brought in the Bulgarians and the French who spoke English in the book and the film too. There were also the Irish players of Quidditch. Charlie works in Romania too, but nothing beyond that. And Ron's family was once in Egypt which seems to have mummies and nothing else is known about it.

There were no Chinese, Japanese, Germans, Spanish, Italian, Australians, Koreans, Caucasians, Indians, Turkish, Ukranians or Russians (sorry for those I didn't list), no mentioning of other countries or regions on our planet.

It seems that the spell system works only in English or rather close to Latin. And the potions and texts, spell books, everything is English only, right? So if in Russia there was magic it should have been in English right? Because other languages presumably don't work, same in Japan or China, or even Chechnya for instance. Maybe the magic there is different and doesn't coexist with the others?

Maybe there isn't magic outside England, France, Bulgaria, Ireland, Romania, Egypt and America at all? I can't find any evidence of magic outside these countries.

The main goal of the question: does magic in other countries differ from that in HP books? Is it the same system of spells, potions and the rest everywhere?

Comment: I’m confused. Bulgarians speak Bulgarian (among others). French people speak French (again, among others). They may also speak English (particularly when in England), but they *are* their own countries.

Comment: Also, perhaps it wasn’t obvious, but Durmstrang had students from all over Eastern Europe, and even beyond (e.g. Malfoy considered it an option). Krum just happened to be from Bulgaria. Maybe there were even some Durmstrang students from Krasnodar. ;)

Comment: Now, if your complaint is that Harry Potter seems a bit…small, a bit provincial, overly focused on the workings of magical Britain, and a part of it at that - well, I don’t disagree. Note however that the Fantastic Beasts films are meant to remedy this to some extent, having already shown one country that wasn’t explored much in the main books. But if you’re not serious in asking whether magic in Harry Potter is limited to (insert seven countries here), and this is a criticism, then it’s not a question.

Comment: Anyway, I’m *inclined* on those grounds to consider this a duplicate of [Why is Harry Potter so Eurocentric?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57095/why-is-harry-potter-so-eurocentric?rq=1/).

Comment: @Adamant It's not criticism, just trying to figure out whether magic is different in other countries and whether it exists there and whether it is English there or not?

Comment: If you're a Russian studying medicine, chemistry, physics, or biology, you'll also find that standard terms favor Latin a lot more than Russian, Chinese, or Turkish. So it actually seems kind of normal.

Answer (score 6):

## The wizarding world spans the whole globe.

Even just considering the seven books themselves and the supplementary books Quidditch through the Ages, Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, and The Tales of Beedle the Bard, it’s clear that there are wizards around the world. Quidditch through the Ages has the most information about international wizards, since if there’s Quidditch in a country there also must be a wizarding community there.

### Africa:

Wizards from Africa were attending the Quidditch World Cup.

> “Three African wizards sat in serious conversation, all of them wearing long white robes and roasting what looked like a rabbit on a bright purple fire, while a group of middle-aged American witches sat gossiping happily beneath a spangled banner stretched between their tents which read: The Salem Witches’ Institute.” 
> <sub><sup>*-Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 7 (Bagman and Crouch)*</sup></sub>

Quidditch is fairly popular there, as several countries have their own teams, and there’s also the All Africa Cup, which is presumably a Quidditch competition for only African countries.

> “The broomstick was probably introduced to the African continent by European wizards and witches travelling there in search of information on alchemy and astronomy, subjects in which African wizards have always been particularly skilled. Though not yet as widely played as in Europe, Quidditch is becoming increasingly popular throughout the African continent.
>   Uganda in particular is emerging as a keen Quidditch-playing nation. Their most notable club, the Patonga Proudsticks, held the Montrose Magpies to a draw in 1986 to the astonishment of most of the Quidditch-playing world. Six Proudstick players recently represented Uganda in the Quidditch World Cup, the highest number of fliers from a single team ever united on a national side. Other African teams of note include the Tchamba Charmers (Togo), masters of the reverse-pass; the Gimbi Giant-Slayers (Ethiopia), twice winners of the All-Africa Cup; and the Sumbawanga Sunrays (Tanzania), a highly popular team whose formation looping has delighted crowds across the world.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

*Supplementary information: Pottermore has an article on [Uagadou](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/uagadou), the African wizarding school.*

### Asia:

There are Ministries of Magic, and therefore wizards, in several Asian countries.

> “Quidditch has never achieved great popularity in the East, as the flying broomstick is a rarity in countries where the carpet is still the preferred mode of travel. The Ministries of Magic in countries such as India, Pakistan, Bangladesh, Iran and Mongolia, all of whom maintain a flourishing trade in flying carpets, regard Quidditch with some suspicion, though the sport does have some fans among witches and wizards on the street.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

Japan has several Quidditch teams.

> “The exception to this general rule is Japan, where Quidditch has been gaining steadily in popularity over the last century. The most successful Japanese team, the Toyohashi Tengu, narrowly missed a win over Lithuania’s Gorodok Gargoyles in 1994.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

*Supplementary information: Pottermore has an article on [Mahoutokoro](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mahoutokoro), the Japanese wizarding school.*

### Australia:

There’s a wizarding population in New Zealand as well, with its own Ministry of Magic.

> “The New Zealand Ministry of Magic has certainly spent much time and money preventing Muggles getting hold of Maori art of that period which clearly depicts white wizards playing Quidditch (these carvings and paintings arc now on display at the Ministry of Magic in Wellington).” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

Australia is also explicitly referenced as having a wizarding community.

> “The Thundelarra Thunderers and the Woollongong Warriors have dominated the Australian League for the best part of a century. Their enmity is legendary among the Australian magical community, so much so that a popular response to an unlikely claim or boast is ‘Yeah, and I think I’ll volunteer to ref the next Thunderer-Warrior game’.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

### Europe:

In addition to the countries mentioned in the question, there are others in Europe that also have wizarding communities, such as Germany, Luxembourg, Portugal, Poland, and Lithuania.

> “In Germany we find the Heidelberg Harriers, the team that the Irish Captain Darren O’Hare once famously said was ‘fiercer than a dragon and twice as clever’. Luxembourg, always a strong Quidditch nation, has given us the Bigonville Bombers, celebrated for their offensive strategies and always among the top goal-scorers. The Portuguese team Braga Broomfleet have recently broken through into the top levels of the sport with their groundbreaking Beater-marking system; and the Polish Grodzisk Goblins gave us arguably the world’s most innovative Seeker, Josef Wronski.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

*Supplementary information: Pottermore has articles on [Beauxbatons](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/beauxbatons-academy-of-magic), and [Durmstrang](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/durmstrang-institute), the European wizarding schools mentioned in “Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire”.*

### North America:

There are wizards in the USA.

> “The rival charms of Quodpot notwithstanding, Quidditch is gaining popularity in the United States, Two teams have recently broken through at international level: the Sweetwater All-Stars from Texas, who gained a well-deserved win over the Quiberon Quafflepunchers in 1993 after a thrilling five-day match, and the Fitchburg Finches from Massachusetts, who have now won the US League seven times and whose Seeker, Maximus Brankovitch III, has captained America at the last two World Cups.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

Canada also has several of its own Quidditch teams.

> “In later times, however, Canada has given us three of the most accomplished Quidditch teams in the world: the Moose Jaw Meteorites, the Haileybury Hammers and the Stonewall Stormers.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

*Supplementary information: Pottermore has several articles on the [history of the wizarding world in America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en), [MACUSA](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa), which is the American wizarding government (instead of a Ministry of Magic), and [Ilvermorny](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny), the American wizarding school.*

### South America:

There’s a wizarding school in Brazil.

> “More to stop Ron smirking than anything, Harry hurriedly pointed out a large group of teenagers whom he had never seen before.
>   ‘Who d’you reckon they are?’ he said. ‘They don’t go to Hogwarts, do they?’
>
> ‘’Spect they go to some foreign school,’ said Ron. ‘I know there are others, never met anyone who went to one though. Bill had a pen-friend at a school in Brazil … this was years and years ago … and he wanted to go on an exchange trip but Mum and Dad couldn’t afford it.” 
> <sub><sup>*-Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 7 (Bagman and Crouch)*</sup></sub>

Many Latin American countries have Quidditch teams, and the region has their own Cup.

> “Quidditch is played throughout South America, though the game must compete with the popular Quodpot here as in the North. Argentina and Brazil both reached the quarter-finals of the World Cup in the last century. Undoubtedly the most skilled Quidditch nation in South America is Peru, which is tipped to become the first Latin World Cup winner within ten years. Peruvian warlocks are believed to have had their first exposure to Quidditch from European wizards sent by the International Confederation to monitor the numbers of Vipertooths (Peru’s native dragon). Quidditch has become a veritable obsession of the wizard community there since that time, and their most famous team, the Tarapoto Tree-Skimmers, recently toured Europe to great acclaim.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

*Supplementary information: Pottermore has an article on [Castelobruxo](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/castelobruxo), the Brazilian wizarding school.*

Comment: And there is no Russia?

Comment: @SovereignSun, http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Russia

Comment: There is also a quote in GoF , where they thank Ludo Bagman for his great game against Turkish Quidditch team.